# Local Lotus Notes Database to be locked down for read only

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-designer

I have an old local copy of a lotus notes database that I need to have the user's access to be read only. Right now they can open a record and change anything inside of it and save it.

Now for every view(role) to show up for anyone, I had to uncheck 'Enforce a consistent access control list across all replicas'

If I don't uncheck that, the views inside the database (records) are not visible. Is there any code I can insert in the database via Designer to lock this down?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the ACL (and any group memberships associated with it) right so that the users are assigned the correct roles. That way you can put the checkmark back on the "Enforce consistent access..." property without users losing access to the views.

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think you'll need to have them pull new local replicas from your server after you correct the ACL in order for their Notes clients to recognize the change in their permissions.